# python FeatureUnion fit_transform works but fit gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to modify my dataframe to replace all categorical attributes with sparse matrices. I combined 3 pipelines using a FeatureUnion. It works perfectly when I use fit_transform, but gives me an error when I try to do just fit instead.
I want to train this pipeline to use it later on test dataset, that's why I need just fit part.
I'm using Python 3

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[3,4,'WN','DEN','SNA',2],[6,1,'WN','FLL','DAL',1],[6,1,'WN','FLL','DAL',1],[6,1,'WN','FLL','DAL',1],[6,1,'WN','FLL','DAL',1],[6,1,'WN','FLL','DAL',1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MONTH','DAY_OF_WEEK','AIRLINE','ORIGIN_AIRPORT','DESTINATION_AIRPORT','SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'])


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values

MONTH_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(['MONTH'])),
    ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
])

DAY_OF_WEEK_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(['DAY_OF_WEEK'])),
    ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
])

AIRLINE_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(['AIRLINE'])),
    ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
])

full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
    ('MONTH_pipeline',MONTH_pipeline),
    ('DAY_OF_WEEK_pipeline',DAY_OF_WEEK_pipeline),
    ('AIRLINE_pipeline',AIRLINE_pipeline),
])


train_set_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(df)
full_pipeline.fit(df)
```

The first command using fit_transform works perfectly and gives a desired answer, but the second one using just fit, gives an error. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand why.

Comment: Its currently not supported. You can see [this issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3890) and [this one too](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3956) and maybe open another issue for your use case.

Comment: Ah, I see. And I couldn't understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks.